# count of same item to calculate count

Tags: sql

i have problem in SQL.

now i have item table and wont to calculate the count of item i sale, i can do it if i sale one item one time like this:

```
 SELECT count(Quantity) AS ItemQ from item group by item_name
```

but if i buy the same item, we must here sub the sale withe buy and count equal 0

so we must the result show me 2 item but i use group by and i cannot calculate count of the same item.

my full query :

```
SELECT count(billsItems_Quantity) AS ItemQ , billsItems_ItemDiscount  , billsItems_ItemName , billsItems_Price , billsItems_SecondPrice  , billsItems_ItemTotal ,bills_StoreID , bills_UserID , bills_ID , billsItems_BillItemSerial, cashier_trans_DocId , billsitems_ItemID , billsItems_Barcode
FROM bills , billsitems , cashier_trans 
WHERE 
bills.bills_ID = billsitems.billsItems_BillItemSerial
and bills.bills_ID = cashier_trans.cashier_trans_DocId
and bills.bills_StoreID = '$ausers_StoreId'
and bills.bills_UserID = '$ausers_ID'
and bills.bills_Status = '1'
```

the table of item is

```
id      item_name   bill_type  count_item   price_item

1        apple      sale         1             20

2        apple      buy          1             15

3        tea        sale         1             10

4       apple       sale         1             20
```

now the count of apple must show to me **1** no **3**

how can i do this in SQL.

Comment: Can you supply your table structures and sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `COUNT` gives the number of rows in the resultset. Therefore to calculate total quantity you need to use `SUM` aggregate instead.

Now to find your total across your items you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT MIN(id), n.item_name, SUM(qty) AS `qty` FROM
(
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, item_name, SUM(count_item) AS `qty`
  FROM item 
 WHERE bill_type = 'sale'
 GROUP BY item_name
 UNION ALL
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, item_name, -SUM(count_item) AS `qty`
  FROM item 
 WHERE bill_type = 'buy'
 GROUP BY item_name
) n
GROUP BY item_name
```

Produces the following output:

```
| ID | ITEM_NAME | QTY |
------------------------
|  1 |     apple |   1 |
|  3 |       tea |   1 |
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ed33/5)

Answer (score 0):

The Count() is aggregate function and you have 3 apples in your table. To get only one you need to partition your data by id - there is only 1 apple within unique id. You probably should use analytic functions to do this as I'm not clear about what are you asking. If you group by id in your first query you should also get 1 in output:

```
SELECT count(Quantity) AS ItemQ from item group by id;
```

Comment: good :) Must now Subtraction sales of purchases to bring what you have purchased how can i do this

Comment: @Zamalek - very sorry pan Zamalek, I cannot understand your question. Subtract what from what? I think you should accept answer from Peterm.